# Android ListView inside RelativeLayout trick

Tags: android, listview

I came to the point, where in my RelativeLayout have to be two TextViews and one ExpandableListView. After long conversation I decided to show pictures in order for you to see how layout behaves itself.

There are snapshots. The first one is when ExpandableListView is NOT Expanded:

[image]

But when I`m trying to expand this ExpandableListView I see the following:

[image]

We can see only little part of expanded list and the color of it is the same as the color of next TextView. Why is it so? My goal is to see whole expanded ExpandableListView.

The code of xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00ff00" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:text="Top User"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/elvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Bottom About"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the code of Activity:

```
public class IngredientsActivity extends Activity {


private ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private final String TAG = "IngredientsActivity";

public void onCreate (Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.ingredients_layout);
    //ingredients = (ArrayList)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ingredients");
    //bitmap = (Bitmap)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
    prepareIngredients();  //preparing ExpandableListView children
    TextView user = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user);
    TextView about = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.about);
    user.setText("Albert Einstein");
    about.setText("Albert Einstein (play /ˈælbərt ˈaɪnstaɪn/; German: [ˈalbɐt ˈaɪnʃtaɪn] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German theoretical physicist who developed the theory of general relativity, effecting a revolution in physics. For thisfor his services to theoretical physics, and especially for his discovery of the law of the photoelectric effect.[5] The latter was pivotal in establishing quantum theory within physics.");
}
     private void prepareIngredients() {
      SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter;
      final ExpandableListView list =                                       (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.elvMain);

      ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
      Map m  = new HashMap<String, String>();
      m.put("groupName", "Datas");
      groupData.add(m);


      String groupFrom[] = new String[] {"groupName"};

      int groupTo[] = new int[] {R.id.groupname};


     ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();
     ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
     for (Ingredient i : ingredients) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ingridient: " + i);
            Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            StringBuilder ingredientsString = new StringBuilder();
            String v = i.getValue();
            if (!v.equals("null")) {
                ingredientsString.append("- " + i.getName() + " " + v + i.getType());
            } else {
                ingredientsString.append("- " + i.getName() + " " + i.getType());
            }
            m1.put("levelTwoCat", ingredientsString.toString());
            childDataItem.add(m1);
     }
     childData.add(childDataItem);

     String childFrom[] = new String[] {"levelTwoCat"};
     int childTo[] = new int[] {R.id.ingredients_second_layer_text};

     adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter (
                this,
                groupData,
                R.layout.ingredients_first_layer,
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                childData,
                R.layout.ingredients_second_layer,
                childFrom,
                childTo);

     list.setAdapter(adapter);       
}
```

The question is the same. How to force ExpandableListView expand in this layout? Now it is not expanded as it has to be. (See the snapshots at the top).

Comment: it is not good practice of using listview inside scrollview

Comment: **"the color of it is the same as the color of next TextView. Why is it so?"** - Items in a `ListView` are transparent - you're setting the background colour of the `LinearLayout` which contains both the `ExpandableListView` and the `TextView` to `android:background="#00ff00"` that's why both of them have the same background colour.

Comment: Ok, maybe. But unfortunately this is not the main issue :(

Comment: **"unfortunately this is not the main issue"** - What does that comment refer to? The one about not putting a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` or my comment about the colours? If your **main issue** is as to why your `ExpandableListView` doesn't contain any list items then you need to post your code for `prepareIngredients()`. If you don't then nobody can answer your question.

Comment: Squonk, comments refers to your comment about colours. Ok, prepareIngredients() posted

Comment: Well for a start, you create a `for` loop as `for (Ingredient i : ingredients)` but you're never initializing `ingredients` which means it will be empty. You've commented out the line in `onCreate(...)` for `//ingredients = ...`. Get rid of the `ScrollView` first of all and concentrate on the `ExpandandableListView`. Initialize `ingredients` correctly and then rethink the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue as @AkashG said, is that you have your `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. Just try to remove your `ScrollView`